Set Theory - how to prove the natural numbers are the positive integers (and similar questions)
I have been working through constructing the real numbers via set theory as a personal exercise. I believe I am following a fairly standard path (based on foggy memories from undergrad math courses) using ZFC as a basis:
Natural numbers are defined to be the set of all "previously defined" natural numbers, so $0$ is the empty set, $1$ is {$0$}, $2$ is {$0, 1$}, etc.
Integers are ordered pairs of natural numbers, or rather equivalence classes of ordered pairs of natural numbers, where $(a, b)$ ~ $(c, d)$ if and only if $a + d = b + c$. The cannonical representatives are $(n, 0)$ for positive integers, $(0, n)$ for negatives, and $(0, 0)$ for $0$.
I've defined addition, multiplication, etc for both sets and proven they are commutative, associative, contain identity elements, etc.
My question is, for example, the symbol "$2$" is now both representing the natural number {$0, 1$} and the integer $(2, 0)$. How do I prove that these sets are referring to the same number? Likewise, rationals will be equivalence classes of ordered pairs of integers (with the reduced fraction as the canonical representative), so "$2$" as a rational will be $(2,1)$.
How do I justify using the same symbol to refer to these clearly different sets? I've tried looking it up, and came across the idea of embedding, but I don't understand the steps needed to prove this. Or maybe there really are different kinds of "$2$" and when referring to the integer or rational version I should be more specific with notation and use "$+2$" or "$2/1$"?
Any help is appreciated, although if possible I prefer hints on how to prove rather than the outright solution. Thanks!

They are not equal. If we really wanted to be serious about formalizing math in set theory, we would have to distinguish them. But in the end, set theory is more suitable as an object of own interest, primarily for studying infinity, than as an actual practical foundation for math. (Which is the main reason why few proof assistants are based on set theory; they mostly use type theory, sometimes higher-order logic.)

@JeanAbouSamra interesting! I really only ever learned about first order logic. My understanding was that ZFC was the more or less accepted standard axiomatic foundation. Is this outdated / was never the case? And do you have any suggestions on what topics I could look up to learn more about the actual foundations of math?

How do you justify the same symbol to mean all of those things irrespective of set theory? How do you justify using $+$ for both vector spaces and the fields they are defined over? How do you justify using $\pi$ for both a real number and a group homomorphism? How do you justify using the same symbol for different thing?

@JeanAbouSamra: In type theory, even more than anywhere else, $2$ in different types is a different object. So I'm not sure that your comment on that really applies here. The point is that we have canonical (and in this case unique) maps from one object to the other which preserve the meaning of things like $2$ or $-3$ or $\frac12$ or $+$ or $\cdot$. And so we can ignore the context in which we consider them, and simply think of them as abstract things again.

@AsafKaragila In type theory you cannot prove (or formulate) that they are unequal ;-) But yeah, you have a point. More generally though, I don't find it enthralling to unravel the laborious encodings of objects in set theory (you have to choose different encodings so that you don't get accidental clashes between unrelated objects, you get junk theorems, etc.). I don't think I've actually seen anyone doing that seriously, we just know it can be done (painstakingly, but in informal math that's fine; in proof assistants not).

@AsafKaragila thanks for your comment, I think I understand your point that these are just symbols, and through context there really isn't any confusion on what is meant. I think the reason this particular question gives me pause is because unlike your example about $pi$ where the real number and group homomorphisms are totally unrelated concepts, the various $2$'s are more interconnected. For example, we say that the naturals form a subset of the integers, yet the natural number $2$ aka {$0,1$} is not an element of the integers.

@JeanAbouSamra: Tangentially, we should stop using the term "junk theorems". It makes it seem, somehow, that asking "what is the domain of $\pi$?" when viewing $\pi$ in a category theoretical way (as an arrow from ${*}$ into $\Bbb R$), or whatever is not equally junk. Languages give you freedom in expression, the onus is on you to make sense. I'm sure we can come up with crazy nonsense that type theories have and set theory doesn't. But somehow "junk theorems" is exclusively referring to set theoretic foundations.

@Sam: But the point about $\pi$ is the point here. It's a symbol. The fact that $2$ behaves the same in all of those structures makes it easy to forget what's what and where's where. You forget that in other foundational systems (e.g. category theoretic foundations) you don't get a coding description of $2$, it's just an object, or an arrow, and it will be different in different contexts just as well. This is not unique to set theoretic foundations. It is a feature, not a bug, and it is freely available in all mathematical foundations, should you choose to use it.

@AsafKaragila Though not coined by me, I see how the term “junk theorems” could be interpreted in a disparaging way. But to be clear, my point is not to say that type theory is somehow “better” than set theory — I view them as having different purposes. I don't think I could find something similar to the so-called junk theorems in type theory, but you only get this advantage (and others) in return for a great complication of the system and the meta-theory. Set theorists at least agree on what ZFC is, but no two type theorists will give you the same version of the calculus of constructions :-)

Incidentally, while I'm not an expert in either set theory or type theory, the best way I know to study the strength of a type theory is to first bi-interpret it with a set theory and then study that with set-theoretic methods. (See my question https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/4532/.)

As you mentioned, $2$ as a natural number and as an integer are different as a set. You can position yourself in various philosophical ones.
One, you can deal with $2$ and $2$ as different things and whenever you want to use these $2$ you can translate each case. For example, when you want to prove $2+2 = 4$, it is OK to prove the facts to each case of natural numbers, integers, rational numbers, real numbers and complex numbers.
Second, if you take an axiomatic perspective, you can more universal cope with such concepts. As for model theory, such natural numbers and integers as sets are models of Peano axioms and integer axioms respectively and plus there is an interpretation of $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(n) = n$. (Note that this done not mean there is an elementary embedding: in fact, there are no elementary embeddings from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ with appropriate languages.) By using this interpretation, we can constantly come to know $2+2=4$ as integers from the fact of natural numbers.
